# In a PostgreSQL/Rails app, what decides how the 'id' field is allocated when 'create' method is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg, libpq

I have a model called "Post". Because of reasons, I had to create Posts with specific `id`  values. When I run `Post.last`, it gives me the Post with the highest `id` value. However, when I run `Post.create()`, it tries to create a Post with an `id` greater by 1 than the `id` of the last Post *created without a specified `id`.*

The number of Posts in my database created without a specified `id` has now caught up to the `id` of the first Post whose `id` I specified. This results in an error, because the Post that Rails tries to create would have an `id` value that's already taken.

Is it possible to somehow override `id` allocation, to make it go by the value of `Post.last.id`?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I'm using postgresql, via the 'pg' gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDs are generated by a Postgres [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-createsequence.html). Rails will have generated this for you as part of a `rails generate model Post`, and if you went with all the defaults, your table is called `posts` and the sequence should be called `posts_id_seq`.

You need to reset the sequence to the next value *after* the ID you've already used.

If the next value you want to use is, for example, 5000, something like

```
ALTER SEQUENCE posts_id_seq RESTART WITH 5000;
```